# gson read same field with different structure

Tags: android, json, gson

Note : This can be achieved easily by creating 2 different GSON models, but i'm looking for a workaround.

I have a model that work with multiple JSON responses. However there is a response :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#playlistItem",
etag: ""fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/jqbcTLu8tYm8b1FXGO14gNZrFG4"",
id: "PLUQ7I1jJqKB4lJarGcpWsP62l7iC06IkE2LDE0BxLe18",
```

That conflict with this one (notice the same `id` field with different type. The above `id` is `String`, the other is a `Class`) :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#searchResult",
etag: ""fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/hDIU49vmD5aPhKUN5Yz9gtljG9A"",
id: {
kind: "youtube#playlist",
playlistId: "PLh6xqIvLQJSf3ynKVEc1axUb1dQwvGWfO"
},
```

Is it possible to just use a single GSON model that can read both responses?

Thanks a lot for your time

UPDATE

This is inside my `Model`, i changed the `id` variable from `String` to a `Class` :

```
private Id id;
public class Id
{
    private String id;
    private String kind;
    private String playlistId;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getPlaylistId() {
        return playlistId;
    }

    public void setPlaylistId(String playlistId) {
        this.playlistId = playlistId;
    }
}
```

This is how i do the request :

```
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Response.class,
                new JsonDeserializer<Item.Id>() {
                    @Override
                    public Item.Id deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                                                    if(jsonElement.isJsonObject())
                        {
                            result.setKind(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString());
                            result.setPlaylistId(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("playlistId").getAsString());
                            //return new Item.Id(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString(), jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("playlistId").getAsString());
                            return result;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.setId(jsonElement.getAsString());
                            //return new Item.Id(jsonElement.getAsString());
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

You can only have id represent single type of variable, in this case on the first response you've got string, and on second case you've got an object, which has a "kind" and a "playlistId"

This seems like a weird design on backend side, but it probably isn't under your control

**Solution**

What you can do is if you think that the id in the first, and second responses are of same type you could create an encapsulating class that would contain these fields like

```
class Id {
    private String stringId;
    private String kind;
    private String playlistId;
}
```

and create a custom JsonDeserializer that would based on the type of the JSON response create a corresponding Id object in following fashion:

```
new JsonDeserializer<Id>() {
            @Override
            public Id deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                if(json.isJsonObject()) {
                    return new Id(json.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString(), json.getAsJsonObject().get("playlistId").getAsString());
                } else {
                    return new Id(json.getAsString());
                }
            }
        }
```

and register it on your gson object, so it would handle the deserialization of Id fields, and depending of its type base its creation

Or then you could create a deserializer that would deserialize the containing object and use different fields based on the type of id, but you should get the idea!

You can register your JsonDeserializer on gson using GsonBuilder and in GsonBuilder calling registerTypeAdapter with the type you're registering type adapter on and with the typeadapter you want to use in the following way:

```
return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Id.class, new JsonDeserializer<Id>() {

    //..

}).build();
```

You can read more about custom typeAdapters in gson documentation, [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Could you elaborate more on how to use the `JsonDeserializer`? Should i use it in my current `Model` class? Because i never used it before, still experimenting now

Comment: The Model class represents the whole response? If you feel like these two type of different id's represent different type of data, you can do that. But if they're same data described in different way, as it seems like, you could use a encapsulating class as described on my post.

I provided a link to documentation on my post and added description of registeration of deserializer!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes the model represents the whole response. I tried to follow your example but get `not an enclosing class` error. Please kindly see my updated question

Comment: The Id is defined within Model but you're refering to Item.Id

Comment: Sorry, i mean my model is `Item` class

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error? That should work.

Comment: I updated my question with my current code. After debugging, i realized method `jsonElement.isJsonObject()` will return `true` even if the value is a `String` (first response)

Comment: I will accept your answer and open a new question, Thanks a lot for your help :)